# Best ways to access class instance attributes in python

Tags: python, class

I have a class, lets say:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.__attr1 = a
        self.__attr2 = b
        self.__attr3 = c

    def meth(self):
        ## run some checks on self.__attr1, self.__attr2, self.__attr3 
                    ## How to do that?  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = testclass("dd", "ee", "gg")
```

Question:
In case I have several attributes and not just three what is the best way to write the `meth` method ? I am going to run the same check on all attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is don't store them as individual attributes. In this example I'm using argument packing to pass `a`, `b`, and `c` as the tuple `abc`, and storing that as `self._attrs`:

```
class testclass(object):
    def __init__(self, *abc):
        self._attrs = abc

    def meth(self):
        for attr in self._attrs:
            print attr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = testclass("dd", "ee", "gg")
```

Comment: Also, if you want to access all attributes to your instance, you can call `dir(self)`, but you'll get built-ins too. Best to grab what you want, having stored appropriately

Answer (score 0):

not very sure about what do u mean by checks on attr

but still i think

def **get**(self, instance, owner):

is something can help u :)